# ignore some part of the link using htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a question about htaccess and it's rewritings.
I have this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1  
RewriteRule ^threads/(\d+)*$ ./thread.php?id=$1  

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ ./search.php?query=$1
```

which `example.com/users/123` is equals to `example.com/profile.php?id=123`.

if I change link to this: `example.com/users/123/John`
**Will htaccess ignore /John or any extra characters after the ID?**
the fact, John is the real-name of 123 ID, I want it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it won't ignore extra parts from your URL since you're using `$` (line end) in the regex here:

```
^users/(\d+)*$
```

Change your rules to:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^users/(\d+) profile.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^threads/(\d+) thread.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?query=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

When I was doing this kind of search friendly readable links, I took the name part in consideration too, it may be important for certain occasions.

If you just ignore everything after the id, then:

```
http://example.com/users/123/John
```

and

```
http://example.com/users/123/Jane
```

would both point to the same user, while the links are clearly different. It is also possible, that John changes his name later to Andrew, but the link with John in it would still point to him. This is some undesired inconsistency in my mind.

My solution was something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)(/(.*))?$ profile.php?id=$1&name=$3 [L]
```

In your code, you can now check if the user with id in `$_GET['id']` has the name in `$_GET['name']` and if it doesn't, you may redirect to the proper link with 301 Temporarily Moved. This way a wrong link may not end up in search indexes, and your users would always see the proper profile urls. Examples:

```
http://example.com/users/123/John -> nothing happens
http://example.com/users/123      -> redirect to /123/John
http://example.com/users/123/Jane -> redirect to /123/John
http://example.com/users/123Jane  -> not found, bad link format
```